# c# linq join three list to nested dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

i have next entities:

```
    public class product
    {
        public string ID {get;set;}
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class subProduct
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string productID { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddValueForSubProduct
    {
        public string subProductCode { get; set; }
        public string AddValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And i want get `Dictionary<string*, Dictionary<string**,string***>>` from this collections:

```
       List<product> products = GetProducts();
       List<subProduct> subProducts = GetSubProducts() ;
       List<AddValueForSubProduct> vForSubProd = GetAddValueForSubProduct();
```

where:

```
   Dictionary<string*, Dictionary<string**,string***>>  
                 *   product.Code
                 **  subProduct.Code
                 *** AddValueForSubProduct.AddValue
```

I trying, but i have recived exception about duplicate key in dictionary.

```
 var res = from p in products 
                      join sb in subProducts on p.ID equals sb.productID into sbs
                      from c in sbs
                      join vF in vForSubProd on c.code equals vF.subProductCode into addingData
                      select new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(p.code, addingData.
                      ToDictionary(v => v.subProductCode, v => v.AddValue));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than try and deal with joining the data and mapping the results of the joins into dictionaries all in a query, it's easier to just create lookups of codes and sub codes to the related lists instead.

Creating the lookups is easy enough:

```
var subProductLookup = subProducts.ToLookup(sub => sub.Code);
var valueLookup = vForSubProd.ToLookup(value => value.subProductCode);
```

And with these lookups you can now map each product to a list of sub-products for that code within a `ToDictionary` call and also map each sub product into all of the values.  Of note here is that technially there could be multiple values for each sub-product, so you either need to choose one (such as the first) or change the inner-most dictionary to look up a collection of values, rather than a single one.

```
var dictionary = products.ToDictionary(
    product => product.Code,
    product => subProductLookup[product.Code]
        .ToDictionary(
            sub => sub.Code,
            sub => valueLookup[sub.Code].First().AddValue));
```